# State of a SignalProducer

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-4

Is it possible to identify state of a SignalProducer in ReactiveCocoa4?

If a SignalProducer has been created, but not necessarily started, is it possible to read a property or call a method to know if a signal has already been started, without actually starting the signal in the process.

Answer (score 2):

`SignalProducer` is a value type (a `struct`). That means that it doesn't have just one owner like a `class` would. When you `start` a `SignalProducer` you're `start`ing **one** copy of it.
For that reason, it doesn't make sense to talk about whether a `SignalProducer` has already been started or not, it's inert.